# Redirect a password protected page?

Tags: password, wp-redirect

I'm looking for the simplest way to redirect a password protected page, to another page after entering the password.

E.g.

```
<?php if ( is_page('name-of-page') && ! post_password_required() ) { 
   wp_redirect( home_url() ); exit; 
} ?>
```

Using wp_redirect is triggering a 'headers already sent error'.

I've seen some solutions using output buffering to avoid this but, I'm not sure if it is the best solution.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't call `wp_redirect` in the middle of a template, it needs to be done before anything else is printed out

Comment: That's what I understood with the headers error. Is there anything you can recommend?

Comment: The only non-hackish guaranteed solution is to do it earlier before the page loads. btw how is a user to read the password protected page? It sounds like you're trying to fix a fix, like the "I know an old lady who swallowed a fly" song? Are you trying to implement a membership area?

Comment: I thought so. No, I'm not trying to implement a membership area. It's just one page, and it's not ideal but it was a request.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time answer. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tom J Nowell confirmed what was happening. Inserting `wp_redirect` in a template causes the page either to partially load or not load at all.

It needed to be placed before the opening `<html>` to work as it would load everything before `</head>` then stop.