# Styling my own password protected page, how to deal with wrong password?

Tags: php, forms, password

Per [these instructions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85581/redirect-a-password-protected-page) I've cooked up a custom password protected page for some of the pages on my site:

```
    <?php if ( post_password_required() ) {


add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'custom_password_form' );
function custom_password_form() {
    global $post;
    $label = 'pwbox-'.( empty( $post->ID ) ? rand() : $post->ID );
    $o = '<form class="grey-form protected-post-form" action="' . get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-login.php?action=postpass" method="post">
    ' . __( "<P>
    PRIVATE. PLEASE USE THE YOU WERE GIVEN BLAH BLAH" ) . '
    <label class="pass-label" for="' . $label . '">' . __( "" ) . ' </label><input onChange="javascript:this.value=this.value.toLowerCase();" name="post_password" id="' . $label . '" type="password" style="background: #ffffff; border:1px solid #999; color:#333333; padding:10px;" size="20" /><input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button" value="' . esc_attr__( "Submit" ) . '" />
    </form>
    <div style="height:700px"/>
    ';
    return $o;
}

  echo get_the_password_form();
```

This is fine except if you test it with a wrong password it just reshows the form. No feedback to the user that he's put in a wrong password.

How can I feed back to my user that he's put in a wrong password?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me adding this code in functions.php:

add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'wpse_71284_custom_post_password_msg' );

/**

- Add a message to the password form.
- 
- @wp-hook the_password_form
- @param   string $form
- @return  string
  */
  function wpse_71284_custom_post_password_msg( $form )
  {
  // No cookie, the user has not sent anything until now.
  if ( ! isset ( $*COOKIE[ 'wp-postpass*' . COOKIEHASH ] ) )
  return $form;

  // Translate and escape.
  $msg = esc_html__( 'La contraseña es incorrecta o ya ha sido utilizada.', 'your_text_domain' );

  // We have a cookie, but it doesn’t match the password.
  $msg = "$msg

  ";

  return $msg . $form;
  }

add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
add_action('wp_logout', 'myEndSession');
add_action('wp_login', 'myEndSession');
function myStartSession() {
if(!session_id()) {
session_start();
}
}
function myEndSession() {
session_destroy ();
}

if ( post_password_required() ) {
$session_id = 'wp-postpass_' . get_the_ID();
//onload
$current_cookie = wp_unslash($*COOKIE[ 'wp-postpass*' . COOKIEHASH ]);
//get old cookie
$old_cookie = isset( $_SESSION[ $session_id ] ) ? $_SESSION[ $session_id ] : '';
//set new session
$_SESSION[ $session_id ] = $current_cookie;
if ( $current_cookie != $old_cookie && !empty( $old_cookie ) ){
error_notification('**Error!** Authentication failed!');
}
}
?>